# Templated ostream operator << for multiple types within a namespace

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a namespace with several structs and enum classes inside of it. For each type, I have a `toString()` method. Here is a small example:

```
namespace test {
    struct A {
       int i;
    };

    struct B {
       float j;
    };

    std::string toString(const A &a){
        return to_string(a.i);
    }

    std::string toString(const B &b){
        return to_string(b.j);
    }
}
```

I want to provide a templated `operator<<` which captures only these types, but not for types outside of this namespace:

```
template<class T>
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &out, const T &t){
    out << toString(t);
    return out;
}
```

However, this gives me the following compilation error:

> error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::stringstream {aka std::__cxx11:basic_stringstream<char>}' and 'const char*')

How can I write a templated operator overload for this?

Comment: There are already many overloads of `operator<<` available in the same scope as your `operator<<`. Your template is in conflict with them, since it matches the same types that the other overloads support. You will just have to specialize your `operator<<` for each type that you have implemented `toString()` for.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: What about using C++20 Concepts? Would that be possible by any chance?

Comment: @einpoklum I can't answer that, as I have no experience with using concepts.

Comment: At the moment I am actually just writing normal overload for every type. I am aware why the conflict happens. I would like to know if it can be avoided. For instance if you can tell the compiler that this template should only be looked at for the types in this namespace.

Comment: For the moment in the project I am working I don't have access to c++20

Comment: The problem is that `test::operator<<(std::ostream &out, const T& t)` is in the `test` namespace yes, but also pulls in the `std` namespace, due to `std::ostream`, and also the root `::` namespace. I don't think there's a way to do something like for "everything in the namespace". You'll need a different class identifying mechanism.

Comment: "*if you can tell the compiler that this template should only be looked at for the types in this namespace*" - AFAIK, there is no way to do that specifically.  However, have a look at [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if), it can probably be used to enable your template only where `toString()` is defined for the template's parameter type.

Comment: `template<class T> auto operator<<(std::ostream &out, const T &t) -> decltype(out<<toString(t)) {return out << toString(t); }` will do what Remy suggests

Comment: In what namespace did you put this `operator<<`?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica it is in the same test namespace

Comment: @MooingDuck Can you provide this as an answer with some more explanation?

Comment: Related: [Templated check for the existence of a class member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/), which could be adapted to handle `toString(T)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it using `concept` & `requires` of C++20 (gcc >= 10.1):

```
template <typename T>
concept HaveToString = requires (T t) {
    { toString(t) };
};

template<HaveToString T>
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &out, const T& t){
    out << toString(t);
    return out;
}

int main() {
    test::A a;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

### EDIT

For `C++11`:

```
template<typename T, typename = decltype(toString(std::declval<T>()))>
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &out, const T& t){
    out << toString(t);
    return out;
}
```

Or as [@MooingDuck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/845092/mooing-duck) mentioned in the comments:

```
template<typename T>
auto operator<<(std::ostream &out, const T& t) -> decltype(out<<toString(t)) {
    out << toString(t);
    return out;
}
```

---

### Explanations

First of all, a really good article about [unevaluated operands](https://humanreadablemag.com/issues/0/articles/what-are-unevaluated-operands-in-c/). It will help to understand what is going on in the expressions: `decltype(toString(std::declval<T>()))` and `decltype(out<<toString(t))` which are both basically doing the same thing-> Setting a rule that any call to this function, have to support the call to `toString` function with the `T` parameter type.

---

### First Approach

```
decltype(toString(std::declval<T>()))
```

Let's split this complex expression into sub expressions, from the inside out:

```
decltype(toString(   std::declval<T>()   ))
```

`std::declval<T>()` In some *very* simple words - means that we are "assuming" we created a variable of the type T at a compile time (If you didn't read the article yet, now it's a really good time to do so). The important thing to know before continue- we didn't do it, the important word is *assuming*.

```
decltype(   toString(std::declval<T>())   )
```

The magic continue all the way up to `decltype` which checking for the type of the unevaluated expression within it. So, if `toString` that calls T type variable exists, it will return the value that `toString` function returns. If this function doesn't exist, a compile time error will be thrown (or in this context, the compiler won't deduce this function for the given type).

```
typename = decltype(toString(std::declval<T>()))
```

This section in the template meant to enable this function whenever the type returning from `decltype` is legal.

---

### @MooingDuck Approach

```
auto operator<<(std::ostream &out, const T& t) -> decltype(out<<toString(t)) { /*...*/ }
```

Return value: `auto`
`C++11`: Deduced by the expression the after the operator `->`.
After `C++14`: Calculated at compile time by the return expression inside the function (if there is no return expression, the return value deduced at compile time to `void`).

```
-> decltype(out<<toString(t))
```

Define the return value type.

```
decltype(out<<toString(t))
```

As explained before, whatever comes inside `decltype` is unevaluated expression. The compiler won't evaluate this expression, but it will make sure that the expression can be evaluated at runtime (or else an exception will be thrown, or in this case, the compiler won't deduce this function), and it will return the type of the returned value from this expression.

Comment: Thanks for this answer but for the moment I don't have access to c++20 in my project

Comment: `template<class T> auto operator<<(std::ostream &out, const T &t) -> decltype(out<<toString(t)) {return out << toString(t); }` is basically the same as the C++ solution, but... much simpler

Comment: @MooingDuck I didn't knew the other way, you just extended my knowledge, and I added it to the response. About the `is_null_pointer`, I was overthinking about this solution, I simplified it. Thanks!

Comment: This actually works for me. It would be nice if you could describe the parts involved.

Comment: @Ashkan I added some explanations, and I hope it clear now. Let me know if there are still some things that you need more details about, it's something that took me a while to understand.

Comment: @KorelK thank you for the explanation. It is quite clear. Just one observation in the code base that I am working on. If there are two types that lets implicit conversion with their constructor then this code do not compile if there is an operator overload for both of them

Comment: @Ashkan please edit your question and add the new issue or create a new question, so I'll be able to refer to it.